# What the function in PyGeoprocessing library that allow to reclassify raster values?

Tags: raster

I am trying to reclassify raster values using QGIS Reclassify by Table but it's falling. I came across PyGeoprocessing Library and apparently it is much faster than R reclassify function. However, I can't find documentation of this library nor tutorials anywhere.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

PyGeoProcessing's reclassification function is called `reclassify_raster`, and can be called like so:

```py
import pygeoprocessing
from osgeo import gdal

raster_path = 'the/path/to/your/input/raster.tif'

# You'll need to load your source and destination pixel values into a dictionary
# like this.  Oftentimes, this will be loaded in from a table.
reclassification_map = {
    1: 0.35
    2: 0.6
}


pygeoprocessing.reclassify_raster(
    (raster_path, 1),  # Use band 1
    reclassification_map,
    'reclassified.tif',
    gdal.GDT_Float32,  # You could use any gdal.GDT_* datatype, this example just uses Float32
    target_nodata=-1  # You could set the nodata value to whatever you wanted it to be
)

It's possible that the maintainers might release some API documentation, but until they do that, you can always just take a look at the function docstrings.  `reclassify_raster`, for example, is found in this file: https://github.com/natcap/pygeoprocessing/blob/main/src/pygeoprocessing/geoprocessing.py
```